# Create Image Patches Using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Let's assume that I have input of 4x4 image with 3 channels with following pixel values:
[image]

And I want to make it to 12 x 9 matrix of image patches like this (using 2x2 kernel on a 4x4 image):
[image]

How can I achieve this using numpy?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sample matrix is x = np.random.random((3,4,4)). This is not same as the image but should work as expected.

Comment: have you tried to solve it already? Can you share some of your work?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data! https://xkcd.com/2116/

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and add in the code to generate your data, rather than putting it in the comments where it is unformatted and harder to find and read. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can see from your example images I would assume a 3x3 mask for copying.
How should a 2x2 kernel work?

Comment: It could be done applying 4 kernels of size 2x2 as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 4x4x3 as input and 12x9 as output

```py
from scipy.signal import convolve
import numpy as np

# creating the 4x4x3 input image
a = np.arange( 1,16+1).reshape(4,4)
b = np.arange(17,32+1).reshape(4,4)
c = np.arange(33,48+1).reshape(4,4)
i_4x4x3 = np.dstack((a, b, c))

# creating four 2x2 kernels
mask_tl = np.array([0,0,0,1]).reshape(2,2)
mask_tr = np.array([0,0,1,0]).reshape(2,2)
mask_bl = np.array([0,1,0,0]).reshape(2,2)
mask_br = np.array([1,0,0,0]).reshape(2,2)
mask_tl = mask_tl[:,:,None]
mask_tr = mask_tr[:,:,None]
mask_bl = mask_bl[:,:,None]
mask_br = mask_br[:,:,None]

# convolving the input with all four kernels
tl = convolve(i_4x4x3, mask_tl, mode='valid')
tr = convolve(i_4x4x3, mask_tr, mode='valid')
bl = convolve(i_4x4x3, mask_bl, mode='valid')
br = convolve(i_4x4x3, mask_br, mode='valid')
i = np.dstack((
    tl.reshape(-1,3),
    tr.reshape(-1,3),
    bl.reshape(-1,3),
    br.reshape(-1,3)))
i=i.reshape(i.shape[0],-1).transpose()

display(a,b,c)
display(i)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])
array([[17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28],
       [29, 30, 31, 32]])
array([[33, 34, 35, 36],
       [37, 38, 39, 40],
       [41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48]])
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  6,  7,  8, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 6,  7,  8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27],
       [18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28],
       [21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31],
       [22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32],
       [33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43],
       [34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44],
       [37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 45, 46, 47],
       [38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48]])
```